# Repeat / tile data in tensorflow element-wise

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to repeat data in tensorflow or keras, and you can use `tf.tile` to repeat `[a, b, c]` to `[a, b, c, a, b, c]`. Is there any straightforward way however to obtain `[a, a, b, b, c, c]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(['a','b','c'], dtype=tf.string)
result = tf.reshape(tf.stack([a,a],axis=1), shape=(-1,))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

# print
[b'a' b'a' b'b' b'b' b'c' b'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's a bit of a hassle to achieve what you want. Here you go:

```
X = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
expanded = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=-1)
#[[1]
# [2]
# [3]]
tiled = tf.tile(expanded,[1,2])
# [[1 1]
# [2 2]
# [3 3]]
reshaped = tf.reshape(tiled,[-1]) 
# [1 1 2 2 3 3]
```